# Проблемы с переводом числа в другую систему счисления и перегрузкой переменной

Tags: python, c#, переменные, системы-счисления

Делаю программку для решения 14 задания ЕГЭ по информатике.
У меня проблемы с переводом кода с языка Python на C#, а также с перегрузкой переменной при больших входящих значениях

**Проблема 1:**

Мне нужно перевести число из 10-ой в n-ую систему счисления. Я нашел пример на языке Python, но при переводе его на язык C# возникли проблемы

Задача:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код на Python, взятый на одном из уроков по подготовке и подогнанный к этой задаче:

```
f = 125 + 25**3 + 5**9 // это формула, данная с задачи
a = '0123456789A'
s=''
n = 5

while f>0:
    s += str(a[f%n])
    f = f // 5

print(s.count('0'))
```

Мой код на C#:

```
class Formula
    {
        static double f = 125 + Math.Pow(25,3) + Math.Pow(5,9); // формула данная в задаче

        static char[] symb = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }; // Алфавит 
        static int n = 5; // система счисления

        static string s; // итог счета "f" в системе счисления "n"
        public static void sCounter()
        {
            var p = "0";
            while (f > 0)
            {
                s += symb[(int)f % n];
                f = f / n;
            }
            int i = 0, count = 0;
            while ((i = s.IndexOf(p, i)) != -1) { ++count; i += p.Length; } // считаем кол-во определённых символов в строке
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
```

В итоге, строка с числом в нужной системе счисления равна не тому, что должно получится, если я буду использовать Python [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема 2:**

Есть задачи, где конечное значение формулы очень большое, из-за чего возникают перегрузки

Например:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как решить такую проблему

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. В варианте для C# переменная `f` имеет тип `double`. Постоянные деления `f = f / n` будут продолжаться до тех пор пока `f` не станет меньше минимального представимого положительного числа. То есть, очень долго. У вас получится много лишних нулей. Смените тип `f` на целый чтобы вернуть правильное поведение.
2. Используйте `BigInteger` для неограниченных целых.

Comment: К сожалению, но при складывании 2^2020 + 2^2017 в BigIntenger, программа заявляет, что оно бесконечное

Comment: Скорее всего вы ошиблись. Покажите код.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Pow(2, 2020) + BigInteger.Pow(2, 2017));` -> `1354390078418883801002213220102850197087959032633525115853050299211041518718986856000380649714293988296754945294452282485771346987944181495605937072439280096840476134352893404782525169446630724524913908659744114216841431184595347407537246351345840535290701373798431574301739144250143283407520370521188590068822861651456985072168357544946862037543699072291780721967575377477236258491762647532635961360193761300917213938507049885664066115257864879163137071389237349298988148394959894416511123606666838336862190082789912...648`

Comment: Да. я просто по другому реализовал BigIntenger, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;         // подключаем для использования BigInteger
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
static void Main()
{
BigInteger resultFormula;      // анализируемое значение (результат вычислений по заданной формуле)            
BigInteger tabValue;           // создание  таблицы степеней основания системы счисления " baseNum"
BigInteger countBit0 = 0;      // инициализация переменной количества значащих нулей 
BigInteger saveBit;            // переменная для записи бита 
int baseNum = 5;               // инициализация основания системы счисления

//  инициализация переменной результатом вычислений по формуле 
resultFormula = (BigInteger.Pow(2, 2020) + BigInteger.Pow(2, 2017));

//  Цикл преобразования значения из десятичной системы в систему счисления с основанием " baseNum"
for (tabValue = resultFormula; tabValue > 0; tabValue /= baseNum)                                      
{
saveBit = tabValue % baseNum;   // определение значения в системе счисления с основанием "baseNum"
if (saveBit == 0) countBit0++;  // счетчик
}            
Console.Write("Количество значащих нулей равно:  " + countBit0+ "\n");
Console.ReadKey();   
}
}
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, ulong при складывании чисел 2^2020 + 2^2017 возвращает 0

Comment: На счет лишних нулей. 
1.В цикле while (f > 0) тип переменной f необходимо сменить на целочисленный тип, иначе образуется бесконечно убывающая геометрическая прогрессия со знаменателем меньшим единицы.
2. s += symb[(int)f % n]; - в данном случае деление по модулю будет выдавать исключительно остаток 0 (то есть первый елемент массива symb).

Comment: Решил вторую проблему с помощью  BigInteger, спасибо Stanislav Volodarsky за подсказку. Если кто обнаружит проблему в моем коде, буду рад критике .